# How to use MPI_Allgatherv on an std::vector of std::vector's?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a situation where every MPI process has a nested `std::vector` that needs to be shared among all other processes with `MPI_Allgatherv`. Here is a minimal example, where I define a 3x2 nested vector with simple entries (in this case the mpi rank).

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int mpi_processes, mpi_rank;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_processes);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_rank);

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> local_data(3, std::vector<int>(2, mpi_rank));
```

I would like to combine the `local_data` vectors to one global vector `{{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{1,1},{1,1},{1,1},...,{mpi_processes,mpi_processes},{mpi_processes,mpi_processes},{mpi_processes,mpi_processes}}`. As I understand `MPI_Allgatherv` should be perfect for this. (In this example all vectors have the same length, but I want to be ready for varying length, hence the `Allgatherv` and not `Allgather`.)

Therefore, I continue to define a `vector` for the global data and the necessary input for `Allgather`, i.e. the receiving count and the displacements.

```
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> global_data(mpi_processes*3, std::vector<int>(2));

  std::vector<int> recvcounts(mpi_processes, 3);
  std::vector<int> displs(mpi_processes,0);
  for(int i = 1; i < mpi_processes; i++)
    displs[i] = displs[i-1]+ recvcounts[i-1];
```

Finally, my idea was to define a MPI data type to account for the fact that I have a vector of 2-dim vectors.

```
  MPI_Datatype mpi_datapoint;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_INT, &mpi_datapoint);
  MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_datapoint);

  MPI_Allgatherv(local_data.data(), 3, mpi_datapoint, global_data.data(), recvcounts.data(), displs.data(), mpi_datapoint, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine, but when I run it, I get a wall of unhelpful error messages starting with

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
Signal code:  (0)
[ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007ff80375cc1d _sigtramp + 29
 *** Process received signal ***
 Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
 Signal code:  (0)
```

Do you know what is wrong here? And do you know if and how I can use `MPI_Allgatherv` correctly on a vector of vectors?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: TL;DR you need to allocate your 2D matrix in contiguous memory (e.g. no jagged array/ vector of vector). `std::mdspan` can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need all the data gathered together? If so, a `vector<vector<>>` is usually not a good idea. Instead, wrap the data in a class where you store a single `vector`, with a 2D indexing function. Or you can use the C++23 `mdspan`.

If you absolutely absolute want that exact structure, you can use `MPI_Type_create_hindexed` and use the absolute addresses of the `.data()` parts of the vectors. But I doubt that that's the right solution.

Comment: Yes, I need all the data in a single ```vector```. Each MPI process computes part of the data set that I want to combine into the total data set for further processing. ```mdspan``` looks interesting, I will check that out.

Comment: It also looks like ```type_hindexed``` is deprecated.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, `MPI_Type_create_hindexed()` is the name of the subroutine. `MPI_Type_hindexed()` has been removed from the MPI standard.

Comment: Sure, and BTW, mdspan does not take an underscore https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan